# YouTube captions API returns inaccurate data

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube V3 API to check if a video has any captions. The example video I'm using in this case is ID [TM3sNH7c5B4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM3sNH7c5B4).

My request looks like this:

```py
def get_youtube_caption_info(client, video_id):
    caption_request = client.captions().list(
            part='snippet,id',
            videoId=video_id,
        )
    caption_response = caption_request.execute()
    return bool(caption_response.get('items'))
```

The client is configured as such:

`client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")`

It keeps returning `True` for this video even though the YouTube video player does not show any options for captions:

[image: youtube settings screenshot]

I added a debugger and this is what the `caption_response` object looks like:

```json
{'etag': 'NdGxn_2Z1vhRrxgcbKpxtLQFSRs',
 'items': [{'etag': 'tOfKO2jRztEqtGHfb_d6vQK_iKU',
            'id': 'Gu_N5R6RDRgeXbUUjChlxQGFyZrSXyjtBetX-fj5KDE=',
            'kind': 'youtube#caption',
            'snippet': {'audioTrackType': 'unknown',
                        'isAutoSynced': False,
                        'isCC': False,
                        'isDraft': False,
                        'isEasyReader': False,
                        'isLarge': False,
                        'language': 'en',
                        'lastUpdated': '2020-10-06T10:28:19.545342Z',
                        'name': '',
                        'status': 'serving',
                        'trackKind': 'asr',
                        'videoId': 'TM3sNH7c5B4'}}],
 'kind': 'youtube#captionListResponse'}
```

It looks like the video player should be showing an option for auto-captions but there's nothing there. Is this a bug on the YouTube side or am I missing something?

Comment: I've never used youtube's api, but since `items` contains some values (hence it is not None), then  casting `(caption_response.get('items'))` to a boolean value will always return true, no matter what these values are.

Comment: @TDG not true. `'items'` is a list, and casting an empty list to a bool will give you a false.

Comment: But in your example the list is NOT empty.

Comment: I've should write 'empty' instead of 'none' in my first comment/

Comment: I know, that's what this question is about. This list is NOT empty, aka the API is telling me that there should be captions available, but based on what the YouTube video player is showing me (no captions), the list SHOULD be empty.

Comment: No, the api may tell you that there are no captions - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions#snippet.isCC

Comment: @TDG, that field isn't useful. It's always `false` regardless of whether or not there are captions present for every video I've tested.

Comment: @Brodan consider then post this problem in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%20status:open) - it *might* be a bug or some undocumented behaviour.

Comment: have you tried this on other videos?

Comment: @Brodan , try your code with video ID: p6X_5rkkA-I

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with Youtube Data API, but a long time ago, so don't remember a lot.

When I tried to download captions for videos with captions, I'd never get those. Only later I realized that many channels don't make captions available for "public" use, i.e. it's come under private data and you can't access them without their permission through your app/script.

So try for some random channels and videos. Here's one of that rare videoID that returned the caption for me : p6X_5rkkA-I

Video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6X_5rkkA-I)